# Hibernate JPA, Bean Validation, and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, bean-validation

How can I programmatically change the ParameterNameProvider used by my Spring + Hibernate JPA application?

I tried to create a validation.xml but I keep getting exceptions saying that "parameter-name-provider" is an invalid element.

So I figured I'd prefer to do it programmatically anyway, but I can't figure out how to modify the validator the system will use with my ParameterNameProvider.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds to me that you are not using the right version of Bean Validation. If parameter-name-provider is an invalid element, you might be using the Bean Validation 1.0 API, instead of 1.1. Programmatically it looks for example like this:

ValidatorFactory factory = Validation
       .byDefaultProvider().configure()
          .parameterNameProvider( new MyParameterNameProvider() )
          .buildValidatorFactory();

But again, you need Bean Validation 1.1.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, something is messed up. Could be an intellij issue. I am definitely using the latest version at runtime but it seems to be parsing an old format. Weird. Btw, the programmatic version, will that cause the default validator that hibernate JPA uses to be the one I configured? Or does it just make "factory" be the one I configured?

Comment: Programmatic approach is for the factory you are creating then and there. If you want to configure the "provided" factory you need to use validation.xml